# Missing required argument `file|environment' - PM2

Tags: next.js, pm2

I am trying to launch my nextjs app through PM2. I have configured PM2 in `ecosystem.config.js` file and starting my nextjs app as `pm2 start my-app`. That's work perfectly fine.

Now I also want PM2 to pull from my github repo then run a custom script that I provided undeer `post-deploy` key. After setting up my github repo through ssh, I tried to run PM2 as `pm2 deploy` but that gives me following error

`error: missing required argument 'file|environment'`

**ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'next-app',
            script: 'npm run start',
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: 'development'
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: 'production'
            }
        }
    ],
    deploy: {
        production: {
            user: 'ubuntu',
            host: ["123.12.12.123"],
            key: '~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub',
            ssh_options: 'ForwardAgent=yes',
            ref: 'origin/branch-12',
            repo: 'git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git',
            path: '/var/www/my-project/',
            'pre-deploy': "git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/branch-12",
            'post-deploy': 'sh nextjs-pm2-deploy.sh'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
pm2 start --only my-app
```